# ProtoBuf Unmarshal JSON into Timestamp

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Trying to see if something like this exists:

```
message TimestampedThing {

    string thing = 1;
    Timestamp date = 2 (layout="2018-03-07T01:00:00.000Z");
}
```

Getting a parse error when I unmarshal it into the GRPC object.

> details: 'json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field TimestampedThing.createdTimestamp of type timestamp.Timestamp'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed jsonpb: https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb

```
jsonpb.Unmarshal(bufio.NewReader(bytes), &pb.TimestampedThing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp in protobuf is wellknown type(consists of seconds and nanos) that is represented in the ISO format, this is taken care in [JSONFormat](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.java) class.

Representation of Timestamp

```
message Timestamp{
  int64 seconds,
  int32 nanos
}
```

Layout is no keyword in protobuf and as far as i know there is no option to define layout/format for Timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Use protojson as google.golang.org/protobuf has been deprecated

See: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson#Unmarshal

Backpacking off Justins response ->

```
    protojson.Unmarshal(data []byte, msg protoreflect.ProtoMessage{})
```